# Finding compatible versions of selenium-java and java-client for WinAppDriver

Tags: appium, pom.xml, winappdriver

I had a project which combined Selenium and WinAppDriver (WinAppDriver for the Windows file chooser, etc).  I had it working in an old project.  Pom files and everything have been updated by users since then so WinApPDriver no longer worked (I received an error about trying to cast the capabilities into a map and they could not be).

I did some investigation and found that these two values were no longer compatible.

```
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>       <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>           <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
```

After experimenting around I cam up with versions that are compatible:  4.7.0 and 8.3.0.
What I was wondering is whether there is a table that shows compatibility for each version, and will changing these versions affect regular Selenium usage?  I looked for a compatibility table but could not find one, and as I said, certain versions will not work together.